# On scroll down add class to next element, and remove the class from parent element

Tags: javascript, css, events, scroll

I was wondering how was this side navigation on [this website](http://buckymaler.com/global/) made? So when you scroll down the next element gets **highlighted**, and previous gets **unlighted**.
In my case, i want to, when i scroll down the next element gets a class of `current` and to the previous element that class is removed. And when it reaches the end and you scroll down it starts again from the first element.

Here is my **snippet**:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #000;
}
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.line-container {
  width: 100px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.line {
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
.current {
  width: 45px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-container" id="container">
    <div class="line current"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need the javascript included on the site as well. Can't do this (easily) with just CSS and HTML. Here's the file: http://buckymaler.com/global/assets/js/functions-min.js

Comment: yes but how am i supposed to understand the minified code? and even if i unminify it i cant understand it, i know i have to add JavaScript, thats why i asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **jQuery** and `Bootstrap` **JS** for making **scroll-spy**. Check out this tutorial: **http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp**
**Scroll-spy** adds class `active` when you scroll to a target element, even without clicking the navigation. Hope this will solve your problem ;)

P.S. Also check out what the `onscroll="yourFunction()"` attribute does.

Comment: @Andrej use onscroll then ;)